# gdb executing the same statement twice

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb

While trying to understand the functionality of the unique_ptr, I wrote following program

```
 1#include <memory>
 2
 3int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 4{
 5    int i;
 6    
 7    std::unique_ptr<int> a(&i);
 8    std::unique_ptr<int> c(a.get());
 9    
10    return 0;
11}
```

When I run this program through gdb I noticed that after "return 0" instruction at line no 10, gdb again goes back to execute line no. 8 instruction.

```
$ gdb ./unptr 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.9-1ubuntu1) 7.9
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400686: file unptr.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/sbahir/work/funstuff/cplusplus/unptr 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdae8) at unptr.cpp:4
4       {
(gdb) n
7               std::unique_ptr<int> a(&i);
(gdb) n
8               std::unique_ptr<int> c(a.get());
(gdb) n
10              return 0;
(gdb) n
8               std::unique_ptr<int> c(a.get());
(gdb) p a
$1 = std::unique_ptr<int> containing 0x7fffffffd9cc
(gdb) p c
$2 = std::unique_ptr<int> containing 0x7fffffffd9cc
(gdb)
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. It would be great if someone could please explain or point to some reference to the material.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, the program could behave in any way imaginable, including printing "Undefined Behavior" because that's what you have.

I'd guess however that it's the dtor of `c` running.

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably the destructors of the `unique_ptr` being executed. The destructors are executed in the reverse order of construction, at the end of the scope (in your case, at the end of `main()`).

**EDIT** Your code is a prime example of **how not to use smart pointers**. Please read the comments below, and also [@MSalters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560071/3093378).

Comment: I don't think the second dtor will be reached.

Comment: @MSalters Can you explain why? Ohhh I see, didn't really parsed the code carefully ;) The `unique_ptr` doubly-deleted the managed pointer. Although I think the second dtor will be reached, but UB will happen inside of it.

Comment: It's not allocated with `new` in the first place, so the first dtor probably corrupts the stack.

Comment: @MSalters Ohh this is really bad, didn't spot that either. Yes you're absolutely right.